# why Change url in Chrome tab it doesn't update tab Url when typing specify url?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I wanna make Chrome extension that when for example I typing this address:

```
ul/g
```

automatic update tab URL to:

```
http://ultra.com/g
```

this is my manifest.json:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "Test ",
  "description": "Test",
  "version": "1.0",

  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.htm"
  },
  "background": {
    "scripts": [
      "src/background.js"
    ],
    "persistent": true
  },
  "permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "activeTab",
    "http://*/*",
    "<all_urls>"
  ],
  "content_scripts" : [{
        "matches" : [ "http://test.com/*","<all_urls>"],
        "js" : ["myScript.js"]
    }]
    }
```

and in my background.js file:

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener( function( tabId,  changeInfo,  tab) {

       if(tab.url=="ul/g"){
            chrome.tabs.update(tab.Id, {url: 'http://ultra.com/g'});
       }
});
```

why this not working?

Comment: Are you wanting it to update when you type `ul/g[Enter]` or just `ul/g` (without pressing the "Enter" key)?

Comment: after press "Enter"

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the entire question is `why this not working?` an answer would be because `ul/g` is not an URL so Chrome redirects the text to a search engine. Here's what chrome.tabs.onUpdated sees:

```
{title: "ul/g - Google Search"}
{status: "loading", url: "https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=ul/g&*"}
{status: "complete"}
```

You can intercept omnibox search requests using webRequest API. For example with google search by default you can see requests like this:

> https://www.google.com/complete/search?client=chrome-omni&..............&q=ul%2Fg..............

So check if the URL has `&q=` parameter that matches e.g. `\w+%2Fg` and [abort it using a `blocking` onBeforeRequest listener](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest), then [update the tab URL](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-update) to `http://ultra.com/g`. You can find examples here on StackOverflow and in the documentation.